# OneTimeSetUp / OneTimeTearDown not executing

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nunit

I am getting warnings from Visual Studio that TestFixtureSetUpAttribute and TestFixtureTearDownAttribute are obsolete and that we should be using OneTimeSetUp/OneTimeTearDown instead.  So, I changed the attributes and now the setup/teardown methods are no longer invoked.

I am using NUnit v2.7.0, VisualStudio 2017 (15.9.7), and the latest version of ReSharper (2019.3.4).  I tried updating NUnit to 2.7.1 (not ready to go to v3.0 at this time), but that didn't help.

What gives?

Dennis

Answer (score 0):

The last version of NUnit V2 issued by the NUnit project was 2.6.4. I created later versions under the NUnit Legacy project in order to assist people who are trying to make the transition to NUnit 3.

Part of what those post-2.6.4 releases do is to issue warnings about things that will be a problem when you convert to NUnit 3. Replacement of TestFixtureSetUp with OneTimeSetUp is an example.

So, if you are not planning to convert anytime soon, then using a version of NUnit V2 later than 2.6.4 isn't very helpful. It has no additional features other than things intended to help with conversion. If you look at the project wiki hope page on GitHub, I think it's made pretty clear there.

OTOH, OneTimeSetUp and OneTimeTearDown are available starting in 2.6.5. If they are not working correctly, feel free to file an issue on GitHub with some sample code and I'll be glad to take a look.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't follow the changes in the nuget versions, and I was not the person who originally upgraded our solution to use 2.7.0, so I just assumed it was all good.  For now, I will continue to use TestFixture SetUp/TearDown.  We may upgrade to 3.x in the future, but it is not a high priority.  I might be able to put together a test project that demonstrates the problem, but again, that won't be a high priority for us unless/until we are forced to upgrade to 3.x (at which time I assume TestFixture SetUp/TearDown will be completely unavailable).